# How to find BitBucket Repository ID

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am really struggling with what should be an incredibly simple task.

As part of an integration between Netlify and BitBucket, I need to pass a bunch of properties to identify my Repository.  I have all of the data points, except it requires the Repo's ID.

I am using BitBucket Cloud and all documentation I can find online is for BitBucket Server.
I've searched here and everywhere else to no avail for the last few hours.

How can I find a specific repo's numeric ID?

Comment: What is that id supposed to be? Usually, the identifier for repositories is `username/reponame`

Comment: Where are you seeing that you need the repository's numeric ID instead of the URL?

Comment: While working with Netlify support.  I'm using their API to create a site which is integrated with my BitBucket account to pull me repo and deploy the site.  The Property sample they gave me was "{"repo":{"provider":"github","id":74777123,"repo":"account_name/repository_name","private":false,"branch":"master","cmd":"jekyll build","dir":"_site/","deploy_key_id":"5a908857a6188f724c466bed"}}"

Comment: Can you share some more information on what you are actually trying to do, and what kind of request you are sending there, and where it’s documented what properties you need? I assume you already tried just leaving the `id` out of that request?

Comment: Sure.  In short I'm using the Netlify API using curl in PHP.  The Netlify Docs discuss creating a site here: https://www.netlify.com/docs/api/#sites .  I am building out my properties to pass to the API and I am able to create the site without any problems.  The issue is when trying to send the repo property so that Netlify will pull my files and then deploy to the newly created site.  Here is my PHP http://codepad.org/qxN8sMOK

Comment: *“It’s a bit complicated to create a repo object so please contact support for guidance if you want to do this.”* – Worst documentation _ever_. Wow. You probably want to stay in the loop with their support on that, so they help you figure out how to get that `id` value. And once you know, please answer the question and provide the information for others! :)

Comment: Did they say that the `id` there was from Bitbucket? It looks to me like the `repo` has the specific details for the repository, and that the `id` is something to do with either the Netlify site or your Netlify account.

Comment: The tech at Netlify has been phenomenal in helping me so far.  Here is the message along with the sample JSON... "Note that there are two ID's there - a github repo ID (which you can get from their API), and a deploy key which you'll need to setup via our API before you'll be able to create a usable repo object."

Comment: Have you asked the tech about Bitbucket repos? There is a UUID that you can get from the BB API (https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories) but they may not need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that for Netlify's API requirement of a Repo ID it is more important when using GitHub.  With BitBucket you can pass the standard user/repo concept.